# boolean.isInstance(true) is false?

Tags: java, class, reflection, field, instance

**Problem**

The Class Object of a boolean Field does not recognize other booleans as instances.

**Code**

```
public class Test {
    public boolean b;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(Test.class.getFields()[0].getType().isInstance(true));
    }
}
```

**Result**

```
false
```

Answer (score 7):

The method is isInstance(Object) so

```
x.isInstance(true)
```

is the same as

```
x.isInstance(Boolean.TRUE);
```

and Boolean.class is not a sub-class of boolean.class.

Note: primitives don't have a `getClass()` method, or any methods for that matter. When you can use it as a Object, it has been boxed.

Answer (score 6):

From documentation of [`Class#isInstance(Object obj)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#isInstance-java.lang.Object-)

> ... If this Class object represents a primitive type, this method returns false.

Notice that expected argument is always `Object`, which means it will always be instance of some class (which excludes primitive types).

Even if you pass primitive type here it will be autoboxed to its wrapper class, but such wrapper class is not be same as primitive type represented by `Class` and in your case returned by `getType()`.